# properly sizing web site

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a web site that best fits the most common screen resolutions.  I would just like to have a basic example to work off of.  Right now, I am creating a navigation bar.  here is the html and css:

```
 <div   id="menuBar">
    <a href="/"> <img id="lmlogo" src="/img/lmlogo.jpg" /></a>
    <div id="labels">
        <a id="about" href="/about.html">about</a>
        <a id="tour" href="/tour.html">tour</a> 
        <a id="recent_jobs" href="/recent.html">recent jobs</a> 
        <a id="success_stories" href="/stories.html">success stories</a> 
        <a id="contact" href="/contact.html">contact us</a>  
        <a id="blog" href="blog.html">blog</a>      
    </div>
    <img id="linkedinlogo" src="/img/linkedinlogo.jpg" style="" />
 </div>

*------------Menu Bar---------------*/

#lmlogo{
    top:.5em; 
    left:.5em;
    position:relative; 
}
#linkedinlogo{
    top:15px; 
    right:5px;
    position:absolute; 
}
#about{
    position:relative; 

    top:0%;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;   
    padding-left:.9em;
}

#tour{  
    position:relative;  
    top:0%;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;   
    padding-left:.9em;
}

#recent_jobs{
    position:relative;  
    top:0%;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;   
    padding-left:.9em;
}

#success_stories{
    position:relative;  
    top:0%;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;   
    padding-left:.9em;
}

#contact{
    position:relative;  
    top:0%;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;   
    padding-left:.9em;
}
#blog{
    position:relative;  
    top:0%;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;   
    padding-left:.9em;
}
```

this looks fine on my laptop (1600X900) but when i lower the resolution it starts to not look so good (font doesnt size well, spacing issues, etc)  How do i maintain a similar appearance regardless of resolution and screen size?

thanks
jason

Comment: Your styles don't seem to correspond to your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a fluid grid for the basis of your layout.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to create your website for 1024 x 768 resloution then wrap every thing within a div that has a display of block something like this :

```
div#parent{ display: block; }
```

then add another div winin the parent like this :

```
div#child { margin: auto; }
```

and this should center everything for you.

for more info see this [Link](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/facebook-style-footer-admin-panel-part-1/)